# PHP call function after header for file download is called

Tags: php, header

I have a function creating a file for download like so:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: filename=file.csv");
print 'hello hello';
exit;

$this->nextFuntion();
```

I need the "nextFunction" to be called after the save dialogue pops up, I've seen various methods around here but they all have to do with header('location:') feature. Basicly the page where the function is called contains the data that goes inside the file. the "nextFunction" will erase the data form the page and return a message etc.

But the best I can do is get the download to work and no function.

Comment: Why do you need to call it **after**?

Comment: You're exiting, but you expect the script to continue?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: It is Schrödinger's script. It is stopped and runned simultaneously.

Comment: @zerkms Well I tried calling it before as well and it didnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split this into two scripts. The first will call the function, and then redirect to the second (via a META refresh or the like) which will be responsible for sending the file to be downloaded.

Comment: Can you expand on "via a META refresh or the like"?

Comment: Pass it in the HTML that you generate in the first script.

Comment: Is there no way to do it without Meta Refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you always want to erase the file immediately after it's downloaded? If the user wants to download it again and it's unavailable, this functionality could annoy them. I'd recommend setting up a cron job to delete all files that are older than a certain time.

Comment: I am the user lol. Its a good point, but for now I'd rather just keep it simple.

Comment: Haha, well it's best not to annoy yourself. If you're looking for something quick and dirty to get the job done, see Ignacio's post.

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is more to do with nextFunction() as PHP should allow you to call functions even after headers are set.

Try it with a test function that just logs to a file or my personal favorite exec("echo 'HAY HAY' | wall ");